# How to search in serialized field using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql database and every record has such as field(field name is stock) which is filled serialized string as below(example data):

```
a:3:{i:0;a:5:{i:1;s:4:"1.30";s:1:"x";s:4:"4.75";i:2;s:5:"11.00";s:6:"update";s:19:"2007-08-12 09:35:12";s:6:"status";s:3:"Run";}i:1;a:5:{i:1;s:4:"1.33";s:1:"x";s:4:"4.50";i:2;s:5:"10.00";s:6:"update";s:19:"2007-08-07 15:51:01";s:6:"status";s:3:"Run";}i:2;a:5:{i:1;s:4:"1.31";s:1:"x";s:4:"4.53";i:2;s:5:"10.10";s:6:"update";s:19:"2007-8-1 21:09:19";s:6:"status";s:3:"Run";}}
```

And such field is serialized by this array as below:

```
array(
   [0]=>Array([1]=>1.30,[x]=>4.75,[2]=>11.00,[update]=>2007-8-12 09:35:12,[status]=>Run)
   [1]=>Array([1]=>1.33,[x]=>4.50,[2]=>10.00,[update]=>2007-8-7 15:51:01,[status]=>Run)
   [2]=>Array([1]=>1.31,[x]=>4.53,[2]=>10.10,[update]=>2007-8-1 21:09:19,[status]=>Run)
)
```

My question is how I can search records whose array['update']>2007-8-7 and array['1']>1.32 of unserialiazed value of field 'stock' ?
Thank you!

Comment: you don't/shouldn't. if you need to do that, chances are that your db's schema need to be changed.

Comment: I found a solution. It is bad. But regexp in mysql is bad too(It doesn't support lazy operations =( )

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL you can use `LIKE` operator to search in string. It will be slower than in normal fields. **If you have 1 value in field**

Example of usage:

```
SELECT {your code here}
WHERE {your field name} LIKE '%[update]=>2007-8-7%'
```

There `%` means any symbols before and after this substring. It will search for this pattern in string

If you want to check multiple values you have 3 options:

**Edit LIKE pattern**

You can edit your `LIKE` pattern to much 2 string:

```
LIKE '%[1]=>1.32%[update]=>2007-8-7%'
```

This string will search for 2 values in string

**Add 2nd LIKE operator**

Second option is to write `LIKE` operator 2 times.
Example:

```
SELECT {your code here}
WHERE
    {field} LIKE '%[1]=>1.32%'
    AND {field} LIKE '%[update]=>2007-8-7%'
```

**Use regexp**

For complex fields like yours you can try to use regexp.
You can perform search by regex using following command:
**WARNING! Bad code syle!**

```
SELECT {your code here}
WHERE {field} REGEXP '[^}]*s:4:"{ARRAY[1] TARGET VALUE}"[^}]*s:19:"{TARGET DATE}[^"]*".*'
```

It will return you all `FIELDS` that contains value that you looking for.
Then you can use find value that you need in your code manualy.

Comment: I want to search value of [1] >1.32 AND value of [update] > 2007-8-7

Comment: @JackyKwan Try to use 1 serialized entity per field. Or do it trough php. Sorry, your query is too complex for me =(

Answer (score 0):

These text strings containing serialized data are not made for searching with pure SQL.   If you try to search them only with pure SQL [Murphy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law) *will* attack you.

So, you need a two stage search. The first stage you'll write in SQL.  It must be designed to get false positives and not false negatives. That is, it should *not  miss* the rows you want, even if it has to pull in some extra rows you don't want. For example, for your date search you want

```
   column LIKE '%2007-%8-%7%'
```

so it will find any row containing`2007-8-7`, `2007-8-07`, `2007-8-07`, or`2007-08-07` (all of which are valid representations of the date).

It will also find rows containing data like  `2007-12-01   2008-01-13  2007-11-19` .  But that's why it's a first stage search.

Then, in your second search stage you should read the matching rows into your php program, deserialize them into their structures, and search for the exact information you need.

You could use REGEXP search instead of LIKE in the first stage. That's fine. But if you want a robust way of searching this information the first stage of your search needs to be written so it doesn't miss any valid data -- doesn't get any false negatives. You may as well keep the first search stage simple.

Others have suggested refactoring your database so it's normalized. If searching is to be a big part of a large scale application, you will do that refactoring job one day. But you can solve your immediate problem with this two-stage tactic.